# How to Manually Generate Instance of Swagger ApiModel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

If I have the following class:

```
@ApiModel
public class SomeEvent {
    @ApiModelProperty(
        value = "The unique identifier of this event.",
        example = "MY_EVENT"
    )
    private final String eventType;

    @JsonCreator
    public SomeEvent(
           @JsonProperty(value = "eventType", required = true) String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }
}
```

I would like to use Swagger to generate an instance and serialize it to the following JSON:

```
{
    "eventType": "MY_EVENT"
}
```

By using this class as a `@RequestBody` in my Spring Boot controller, the expected serialized form is displayed perfectly on the Swagger UI.

However, I'd like to be able to generate an instance (where the instance's fields contain the values from the `example` in the `@ApiModelProperty`) using code. I've searched around and could not find a single example of how to do this, assuming it's possible to achieve.

**Note**: I do not want to just create an instance using `new SomeEvent("MY_EVENT");`, but rather use `Swagger` to grab the examples.